# Cracked Phone Screen

Tags: professionalism

Does a cracked iPhone screen appear unprofessional to clients and management?

When someone pulls out a phone with a cracked screen, do you have any immediate negative judgments toward that person?

Comment: Personal phone or company phone?

Comment: Some people will some people won't. While all our questions are opinion-based to some extent, I don't see how this can be meaningfully answered.

Comment: To me, the question is answered thanks to Joe's comment.

Comment: Why are you pulling out your phone when meeting with a client? If it is to answer a call or text, then don't do it whether the screen is cracked or not. If it is to show some information the client needs, then you need to either fix the phone immediately or at least mention that you cracked the phone on the way there and make sure it is fixed before you see that client again. Coworkers will give you more grace if they know you, but it does not represent your company well any more than dirty wrinkled clothing.

Comment: Your outside image is of some importance during client meetings. The appearance includes the choice of attire, including shoes, cleanliness, smell, haircut, and the quality and state of any tools you use, such as cars and phones. The less client facing you are, the less relevant it is to project a perfect image. Depending on the client, your appearance can also be too perfect - don't wear a suit in a soup kitchen!

Comment: It's more the norm than exception to have a cracked screen nowadays. They don't build them like they used to. I doubt anyone will even pay attention to that.

Comment: "When someone pulls out a phone with a cracked screen..." - when someone pulls out their phone, a normal person would not look closely enough at the someone's screen to see whether it's cracked.

Comment: Phone screen integrity is not among professionality tellsigns, anyway a one-time occassion can be saved with very short mishap explanation. On the other hand, cracked phone screen can cause negative second thoughts ("how much you can safekeep and care posessions"), and if considered to be corporate image part, then it is important for the company to not show that image. Depends of the profile and customer relations. For an on-site deployment team I don't care for cracked screen. For a company representative, I care.

Comment: @JuhaUntinen They might not "build them like they used to" but I've still managed to own four smartphones in the last five years, not use any kind of case or screen protector, and not have even a tiny crack on any of the screens, let alone a completely smashed screen. To me, personally, it shows a lack of ability to take care of your possessions (because you smashed it in the first place) and then a continued lack of caring about what they look like (because yes, accidents happen, but then you choose to not replace the screen).

Comment: (cont.) I get that replacing a phone screen can be expensive, and that it's not something everybody can afford. However, if I'm meeting with somebody in a professional setting, I'd expect that the phone is a company, rather than personal, phone and/or they're paid enough that replacing a damaged screen when required definitely is an option.

Answer (score 9):

Quite obviously I could have broken the screen of my phone just on the way to work, and there's not much I can do about it until the weekend.

If my phone doesn't get repaired for weeks, and my management doesn't want clients to see me with a broken phone, then there is an easy solution: Pay for a company phone.